# How to out put nohup pid to top command?

Tags: linux, shell

How could I running nohup and output the pid to top command? I use command like this `nohup mycommand 2>&1 & | top -p` but terminal show the info like `syntax error near unexpected token |'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pipe the output of a background process to a foreground process. Also, the PID that's printed when you start a background process doesn't come from the process itself, it's printed by the shell, so it wouldn't be in the pipe anyway.

And `top -p` doesn't read the PID from standard input, it has to be an argument to the program.

The variable `$!` contains the PID of the most recent background process.

```
nohup mycommand 2>&1 &
top -p $!
```

Answer (score -1):

try to get only the numbers, something like 
nohup mycommand 2>&1 & | grep '[0-9]' | top -p

Comment: The pipe only redirects the output of the program, not messages from the shell like the PID of the background process. And you can't pipe from a background process, that's why it gets a syntax error from `& |`.

Comment: Also, `top -p` doesn't get the PID from standard input, it needs to be the argument to the `-p` option.